# How to use a Heegaard diagram to retrieve the original 3-manifold that it represents?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, knot-theory, heegaard-floer-homology

(Disclaimer: I apologize that this is an introductory question for a forum like MathOverflow, but I have run out of ideas and resources to understand how this works, and I don't know where else to ask this.)

Recently, I have been reading the book *Floer Homology, Gauge Theory, and Low-Dimensional Topology* by Szabó et al., and I’ve been struggling to understand an important idea in the first paper of the text entitled *An Introduction to Heegaard Floer Homology*.

First, some background. Let $Y=U_0\cup_{\Sigma_g}U_1$ be a Heegaard decomposition for genus-$g$ handlebodies $U_0$ and $U_1$, and let $(\Sigma_g, \boldsymbol{\alpha}, \boldsymbol{\beta})$ be a Heegaard diagram for $g$-tuples of attaching circles $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_g)$ and $\boldsymbol{\beta}=(\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_g)$ on $U_0$ and $U_1$ respectively. According to the authors, the genus $1$ Heegaard decomposition of $\mathbb{S}^3$ corresponds to a diagram $(\Sigma_1,  \boldsymbol{\alpha}, \boldsymbol{\beta})$ where $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=\{\alpha\}$ and $\boldsymbol{\beta}=\{\beta\}$ meet transversely at a unique point. Visually, this would look something like this:

[image]

With all of this in mind, here is my question:

**Question:** How do we take this Heegaard diagram and manipulate it to obtain $\mathbb{S}^3$? More generally, how does one take a Heegaard diagram and produce the original $3$-manifold that it represents?

I’ve tried searching for [lectures online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=WWFM3Ua0WY4&list=PLldN_DpkXL3aPMfyZRWQ7sW61d72HSoZj&index=1) that attempt to explain this, but their explanations were pretty "handwavy" and no one in the audience asked any clarifying questions for them to elaborate. I've even consulted a lecture that took place in 2022 from the [very author of this paper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=p3_qkX_igOY), but their explanation was even shorter than the former.

I would *greatly* appreciate a visual/comprehensive/clear explanation for how to do this (to retrieve the original three manifold from a Heegaard diagram), and pictures/drawings of what is going on would be amazing.

**An incentive to post an answer**: I've (of course) tried scouring the web before asking here, and I don't believe there are any resources (lectures, texts, papers on the ArXiv, or handouts) that provide a clear explanation on how to do this (instead of, say, "just glue this and that, and it's the original 3-manifold!"), so an answer to this question could spare future readers/students the potential pain of learning about Heegaard diagrams for the first time.

Comment: This Heegaard splitting of $S^3$ comes up in Hatcher's algebraic topology notes, for example.  You see it a few times in the notes, but his description of the Hopf fibration is one clean location.  Specifically, given the Hopf fibration $S^3 \to S^2$, decompose the base $2$-sphere as a union of two discs, then their pre-image is the genus-1 Heegaard splitting of $S^3$.

Comment: I think that this is not a question about topology, but rather about learning mathematics at the graduate level.  So I suggest that we leave it open, and answer it in that spirit.  (At least, that is what I tried to do!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** The key is in the phrase "produce the original three-manifold that it represents?".  The answer is you do *not* recover the original manifold. Instead the Heegaard splitting gives a *new* manifold which is homeomorphic to the original.

---

**Long answer:** As concrete example, let us take $P^3 = \mathbb{RP}^3$ as our original manifold.  For this to make sense, we have to fix an actual definition.  Let's use the following: "the set of lines in $\mathbb{R}^4$ equipped with the topology coming from the angle metric".  Suppose now that $M^3$ is a three-manifold given by a Heegaard diagram in the two-torus with Heegaard curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$ meet (essentially) exactly twice.  I claim that $M^3$ is homeomorphic to $P^3$.

[It is meta-mathematically interesting to ask if $M$ "equals" $P^3$.  But that question is not relevant to somebody learning three-manifolds (or any mathematical subject) for the first time.]

To prove that $M^3$ and $P^3$ are homeomorphic, we need to give continuous maps in both directions.  Usually people do this by finding a cell decomposition of $P^3$ which is isomorphic to the "given" cell decomposition of $M^3$ (that is, the decomposition coming from the diagram.)  To give a cell decomposition of $P^3$ we have to actually make contact with the given definition of $P^3$.  In this case, we have to herd sets of lines in $\mathbb{R}^4$ into disks, two-tori, solid tori, and so on.

**That is:** to give the homeomorphism, you (the reader) have to deal with the original definition of $P^3$.  This depends sensitively on which original definition you (the reader) chose.  At the graduate/research level, the writer is not going to take the time to set out *their* original definition of $P^3$.  Also, they can't know (and don't care) which definition you chose.  So they leave finding the homeomorphism as an exercise for you.

---

As a final remark: in Heegaard Floer homology sometimes orientations are incredibly important.  In these cases the authors should give an actual definition of the original manifold, in order to nail down the orientation.  But they will almost certainly still leave finding the (orientation preserving!) homeomorphism as an exercise for the reader.